# BigQuery error handling

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a "better" way of handling errors while loading data?

For example:

```
With schema:
ONE:STRING,TWO:INTEGER,THREE:INTEGER

And Data: 
        ABC, 123, 234
        DEF, D, 324
        XYZ, 12334, 423
```

Is there a way I can load this to a table by ignoring *only* column TWO and not entire row two? 
That is result in:

```
ABC, 123, 234
DEF, NULL, 324
XYZ, 12334, 423
```

Instead of:

```
ABC, 123, 234
XYZ, 12334, 423
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is change column TWO to a string:

```
TWO:STRING
```

Then you can query column2 like this:

```
Select INTEGER(expr) from yourTable;
```

If value is not an integer then it will return NULL (exactly like you want).